# FULLTEXT MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to make a FULLTEXT query and encountering an error.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT `o`.`fruits_id` 
FROM `fruits` as `o` JOIN `fruits_categories` as `oc` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `oc`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `categories` as `c` ON `c`.`cat_id` = `oc`.`cat_id` 
JOIN `fruits_location` as `ol` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `ol`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `location` as `l` ON `l`.`location_id` = `ol`.`location_id` 
JOIN `fruits_price` as `op` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `op`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `price` as `p` ON `p`.`price_id` = `op`.`price_id` 
WHERE ( (MATCH (o.fruits_name, o.fruits_description, o.address, o.instagram_tag) AGAINST ('apple') OR MATCH (c.cat_name) AGAINST ('apple') OR MATCH (l.location_name) AGAINST ('apple') OR MATCH (p.price_name) AGAINST ('apple') ) 
AND (MATCH (o.fruits_name, o.fruits_description, o.address, o.instagram_tag) AGAINST ('orange') OR MATCH (c.cat_name) AGAINST ('orange') OR MATCH (l.location_name) AGAINST ('orange') OR MATCH (p.price_name) AGAINST ('orange') ) )
```

on the tables I have:

fruits

```
FULLTEXT KEY `fruits_name` (`fruits_name`),
FULLTEXT KEY `fruits_description` (`fruits_description`),
FULLTEXT KEY `address` (`address`),
FULLTEXT KEY `instagram_tag` (`instagram_tag`)
```

categories

```
FULLTEXT KEY `cat_name` (`cat_name`)
```

location

```
FULLTEXT KEY `location_name` (`location_name`)
```

price

```
FULLTEXT KEY `price_name` (`price_name`)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you indexed your fields separately in the fruits table, but you try to search them in a combined way in your query! Drop the existing fulltext indexes in the fruit table and create a new composite index on those 4 fields.

Comment: Is it normal that this query takes 3 secs when directly ran in phpmyadmin an about 12 seconds on a page?

Comment: Phpmyadmin automatically places a limit at the end of any select query. If you have a lot of records, this could be a differentiator. Otherwise, no, there should not be a significant difference.

Comment: there are about only 200 rows for the fruits table

Comment: Is there a better query that can fully optimize it? btw, in the php code, I had LIMIt 9 which is smaller than the default in phpmyadmin

Comment: In this case sg else must cause the lag. You should post this as a separate question with php code and explains attached.